# How do I take a screenshot of my project file, and then export/convert said file into a PDF, using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am trying to take the contents of my project file and turning/export it as a PDF. For context, here is the layout of my project file:

[image: My project file (tax calculator, essentially)]

Don't mind the numbers, I was just testing that part of the code, my only issue is finding a way in taking that project file and turning it into a PDF. I tried breaking down this task into two buttons, the *2) Save File* and *3) Create PDF* buttons, though now I'm just getting more confused the more I try to do this.

Here is my code for the "2) Save File" button:

```
Private Sub Screenshot_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Screenshot.Click
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)

    Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))

    PictureBox1.Image = bmp

    bmp.Save(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\" & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save file"
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "E:\French"

    Dim location As String

    location = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    bmp.Save(SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
End Sub
```

The *3) Create PDF* button doesn't currently have any special code, all I did was to try and create a bitmap and then taking that bitmap and turning it into a PDF:

```
Private Sub PDFbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PDFbutton.Click
    Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    ' Create a graphics object from the bitmap  
    Dim gfxScreenshot As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)
    ' Take a screenshot of the entire Form1  
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, Me.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    ' Save the screenshot   
    bmpScreenshot.Save("D:\Form1.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub
```

Just started working on vb.net, so I'm still new at this. I'll gladly take any help and/or advice!

Comment: There are number of third party libraries available specifically for creating and manipulating PDF documents.  Perhaps start with looking through nugets

Comment: What are you going to do with the pdf?

Comment: @Mary It's for a close relative of mine, he wants to see if I can make a WinForms application to help him in his business. I guess its easier to read, I don't really know, I just need to know how to create a PDF document for him.

Comment: You can create a Word document with interop and covert that with Word.